# Checking if date belongs to array of dates in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a document that describes a Practitioner like this

```
{
   name: String;
   schedules: {
     weekend: [Number],
     timings: [{ 
       from: {hour: Number, minute: Number},
       to: {hour: Number, minute: Number} 
     }]
   }
}
```

I want a way to check if a date hours and minutes are included in the timings array using mongoose/mongodb but I am unable to figure this out as I was not able to find any documentation/question about this issue

**Edit 1:**

my input value is a javascript ISO date, and the expected result is true or false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query

- instead of `ISODate("2017-01-01T02:46:12Z")` put your date variable
  in both places
- the first let creates a date variable to be used for the comparison
- reduce starting from false
- if no find match yet
- check if   from_date(convert first) <= your_date <= to_date(convert_first)
- else if match is already found keep the true value
- if at least one matches all reduce will evaluate to true
- set that true/false value to a new field
- you can filter it after if you want, to keep false or true documents

[Test code here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/mrV8jBkQKMr)

```js
aggregate(
[{"$set": 
    {"date-in-timings": 
      {"$let": 
        {"vars": 
          {"your_date": 
            {"$dateFromParts": 
              {"year": 2021,
                "hour": {"$hour": ISODate("2017-01-01T02:46:12Z")},
                "minute": {"$minute": ISODate("2017-01-01T02:46:12Z")}}}},
          "in": 
          {"$reduce": 
            {"input": "$schedules.timings",
              "initialValue": false,
              "in": 
              {"$cond": 
                [{"$not": ["$$value"]},
                  {"$and": 
                    [{"$gte": 
                        ["$$your_date",
                          {"$dateFromParts": 
                            {"year": 2021,
                              "hour": "$$this.from.hour",
                              "minute": "$$this.from.minute"}}]},
                      {"$lte": 
                        ["$$your_date",
                          {"$dateFromParts": 
                            {"year": 2021,
                              "hour": "$$this.to.hour",
                              "minute": "$$this.to.minute"}}]}]}, "$$value"]}}}}}}}])
```

Comment: this worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

Use [$dateToParts](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateToParts/), it gives a result like this:

```
"timeParts" : {
    "isoWeekYear" : 2021.0, 
    "isoWeek" : 41.0, 
    "isoDayOfWeek" : 1.0, 
    "hour" : 19.0, 
    "minute" : 58.0, 
    "second" : 56.0, 
    "millisecond" : 685.0
}
```

Then you can compare fields `isoDayOfWeek`, `hour` and `minute` with your values. As you did not provide any input values or expected result, it is difficult for me to propose a concrete solution,

Comment: my input value is a javascript ISO date, and the expected result is true or false. I just want to make sure that the date passed to my route is available in the timings array or not

Comment: Please provide some real and valid sample input data, then I will create a real solution.